# Bind the ServiceController objects to a List through LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class of 4 Strings. I am trying to iterate through each Windows service using ServiceController and then Binding it to the List of Class Object.

Which of the two option will be better and how to do both of them

My Goal is to bind this list to the Gridview as a Datasource.

```
public class ServiceDetails
{
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}


protected void GetAllServices(string machinename)
{
    ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices(machinename);
    List<ServiceDetails> svcdetails = new List<ServiceDetails>();

    // option 1 - to iterate through each and bind to list
    foreach (ServiceController service in services)
    {
        //How to bind the servicecontroller object to a list.?
    }

    // option 2 - Bind the List using LINQ query
    List<ServiceDetails> items = svcdetails.ForEach(service=> LINQ Query...?

    Gridview.DataSource = items;            
    Gridview.DataBind(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that you have added the following:

```
using System.Linq;
```

then do the following:

```
var items = services.Select(s=>new ServiceDetails{
 ServiceName = s.ServiceName,
 Status = s.Status,
 Description = s.Description,
 Location = s.Location
}).ToList();
```

I am assuming the property names of the class ServiceController. Then,

```
Gridview.DataSource = items;
```

after doing that you will have to configure Column mappings in the View/aspx page